# Combining a content management system with ASP.NET

Tags: cms, security, asp.net, drupal, authentication

I am going to be creating a site that seems like it requires a blend of a content management system (CMS) and some custom web development (which is done in ASP.NET MVC).  I have plenty of web development experience to understand the ASP.NET MVC side of the fence, but, I don't have a lot of CMS knowledge aside from getting one stood up.

Right now my biggest question is around integrating security from ASP.NET with the CMS.  I currently have an ASP.NET MVC site that handles the authentication for multiple production sites and creates an authentication cookie under our domain (*.example.com).  The page acts like a single sign on page since the cookie is a wildcard and can be used in any other applications of the same domain.

I'd really like to avoid having users put in their credentials twice.  Is there a CMS that will play well with the ASP.NET Forms Authentication given how I have these existing applications structured?

As an aside, right now I am leaning towards Drupal, but, that isn't finalized.

Answer (score 1):

I've found DotNetNuke to be a reliable a.Net CMS solution. I've easily built several modules, even my own SSO authentication provider.Not sure if they support MVC though, but I would give them a try. Its open source and you get the Telerik control suite out of the box. There is a HTML boilerplate skin you can download that will get you started with the most essential development tasks.

What specific features of a CMS do you require?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a CMS that's build upon / supports ASP.NET MVC ?

While Drupal is powerful and flexible, you're talking about 'a blend' so you probably end up doing more integration/customization than just authentication. Sticking to the .NET side might be easier in the long run than mix-n-matching ASP.NET MVC & PHP.

Have you taken a look at Sitefinity v5? (disclaimer: I'm a Sitefinity MVP) Since version 5.1 it fully supports MVC, Webforms and even a patented hybrid cross that will easily get you squared away. Its not open-source, but like Telerik's controls its just awesome userfriendly and thought thru - so the lack of dev/user training might make up for that.

They're fully supporting forms authentication but also allow for a claims-based approach in case you ever want to upgrade or go more secure. Here's a link to their documentation:

[Sitefinity Authentication Models](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/authentication-models-overview)